# raw escape in python except last char

Tags: python

Why in python I can't use:

```
r"c:\"
```

Comment: seems like a bug to me. same thing with r"""C:\"""

Comment: Not a bug.  It's certainly a wart, but it is part of the language definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a string must contain the same quote character with which it starts, escaping that character is the only available workaround -- so the design alternative was either to make raw-string literals unable to contain their leading quote character, or keep the "backlash escapes" convention, even in string literals, just for quote characters.

Since raw-string literals were designed for handy representation of regular expression patterns (not for DOS / Windows paths!-), and in RE patterns a trailing backslash is never necessary, the design decision was easy (based on the real use case for raw-string literals).

Comment: a good complement is this blog article http://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2008/06/04/gotcha-%E2%80%94-backslashes-in-windows-filenames/

Answer (score 1):

Use `"c:/"` or `"c:\\"`.  Raw string literals are for escaping escape-sequences, not for including literal backslashes, though they do work that way, except in this exact case.

Answer (score 1):

Its a known case I think, better use "c:\\" for that case.

Comment: but  r"c:\\" is interpreted as 'c:\\\\'

Comment: This is presumably why Mark said `"c:\\"` and not `r"c:\\"`.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals):

> ... a raw string cannot end in a single backslash (since the backslash would escape the following quote character).

.

Answer (score 0):

Even with raw strings, `\"` causes the `"` not to be interpreted as the end of the string (though the backslash gets into your string), so `r"foo\"bar"` would be a legal string. This is convenient enough when writing regex but not great for writing paths.

This is not a big deal as most of the time you should be using `os.path` and other modules to deal with your paths.

Answer (score 0):

found in  Design and History FAQ http://docs.python.org/faq/design.html#why-can-t-raw-strings-r-strings-end-with-a-backslash

> Raw strings were designed to ease
>   creating input for processors (chiefly
>   regular expression engines) that want
>   to do their own backslash escape
>   processing. Such processors consider
>   an unmatched trailing backslash to be
>   an error anyway, so raw strings
>   disallow that. In return, they allow
>   you to pass on the string quote
>   character by escaping it with a
>   backslash. These rules work well when
>   r-strings are used for their intended
>   purpose.